# how do I perform a find that will generate the file path and content in two different variables

Tags: bash

I have a base script that runs a find command like this:

```
var = `find /some/path *.ext -type f -exec cat {} +`
```

Now in `$var` I only get the content of the files, but I need both the paths and the content, preferably in two separate variables. Is this possible?

With find I either get the path or the content but not both and not in two variables.

Comment: I don't think there's any straightforward way to do this. Do it in two steps: First get a list of all the filenames in one variable, then loop through that list getting the contents.

Comment: Check your syntax at https://shellcheck.net. Be sure to include proper first line of code, usually `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

@Barmar is right, it's a 2 step process. Try this

```bash
mapfile -t files < <(
    find /some/path -type f -name \*.ext -print
)
```

That creates an *array* of filenames. `mapfile` puts each *line* of input into an array element.

Then

```bash
content=$(cat "${files[@]}")
```

Assumes your filenames do not contain newlines.

Comment: Depending on bash version you could add `-d ''` to the `mapfile` and use `-print0` to handle newlines safely.

Answer (score 1):

In perl and sh, sometimes it's nice to have every line of output tagged.

Quick and easy way to do it ( if it's a text file ) is

```
find -type f -name '*.c' |xargs grep .*
```

grep lists the filename, a colon, and then the content for each line.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to populate an associative array with path as key and content as value like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A assoc="($(
  find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec \
    bash -c '
      for f; do
        read -rd "" c < "$f"
        printf "[%q]=%q " "$f" "$c"
      done
    ' _ {} +
))"
```

How it works:

`find` will pass each file path to this inline bash script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Process each file path from arguments
for f; do
  # Store content of file in c
  read -rd "" c < "$f"
  # Format output of file path and content as an associative array
  # entry with properly quoted strings
  printf "[%q]=%q " "$f" "$c"
done
```

One-liner version:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A assoc="($(find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'for f;do read -rd "" c <"$f";printf "[%q]=%q " "$f" "$c";done' _ {} +))"
```